# Windows Server 2012R2 access denied when changing files

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions

I have been running Windows 2012r2 in testing for a while. One of the things keeping the OS from going into production is "Access Denied" message when changing config settings in either Program Files or Inetpub.

I do have domain admin privileges on the server and included in administrators group on the local server.

UAC has been disabled to the point this was added to the registry:
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system]`

`"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000`

Yes it may be "unsecure" in some eyes. However I am grasping at straws to allow file editing in these folders.

Please help.

Comment: So, you don't know what UAC is, and you're letting that prevent your employer from upgrading their server OSes?  That's... terrible.  For so many reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not, that you don't have enough access - the issue is: You need some access elevation to access these folders.

Just check out extending the NTFS security permissions with your user (or better a usergroup that represents users with this access requirement) on the desired paths and you shouldn't be prompted anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If your permissions on the file are granted through the local administrators group, then you will need to run notepad (or whatever editor) as administrator. If the permissions are granted to the domain admin group, or any other group or user for that matter, you should not see this issue and will be able to edit the file without elevation.